# openliberty 22.0.0.7 - unable to install features

Tags: open-liberty

I have installed openliberty 22007, and am trying to install the samlWeb-2.0 feature.  This fails with

./featureUtility installFeature samlWeb-2.0 -v
Initializing ...
Using 8 threads to download artifacts.
CWWKF1409E: Unable to find the following feature JSON files locally or on the configured Maven repository: [io.openliberty.features:features:22.0.0.7].

If I try to run ./featureUtility find - it also fails with the same message.  Other openliberty runtimes I have installed work.

Comment: I installed 22.0.0.6, and the installFeature works

Comment: I had the same issue, downgraded to 22.0.0.6 and now resolved.

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause this, I am able to download features using 22.0.0.7. In addition, the feature JSON files it complains are missing are available on maven central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/openliberty/features/features/22.0.0.7/